# Python using variables between 2 scripts with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I'm working on 2 scripts, I need one of them to share a string variable with the other script.
The 2 scripts are running in infinite loops, so I use multiprocessing to run them simultaneously.
The variable value doesn't seem to change, whatever the approach I try. I have tried the following:

1. Using a global variable updating it in the first script and importing it in the second.
2. Using a class with the variable as one of its attributes, having one function to update it and another to get its value.
3. Using a third script that defines a global variable and importing it from both.
4. Passing a list to the second script object to be updated, and read it later.
5. Using lists and dictionaries. This made the code stuck, for no reason.

**It always returns an empty string.**

Snippets from the first script

```
class TelegramUpdater():

    def __init__(self):
        self.text_to_pass = ""

    def update(text):
        self.text_to_pass = text

    def save_longer_text(self):
        return self.text_to_pass
```

Snippets from the second script

```
import multiprocessing
from dialogtelegram_oop import TelegramUpdater

# initialize the flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

telegram_app = TelegramUpdater()


#####

note_list = telegram_app.save_longer_text()

#####


def telegram_app_run():
    telegram_app.telegram_run() 


def flask_app():
    app.run()

   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    flask_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=flask_app, )
    telegram_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=telegram_app_run, )
    jobs.append(flask_process)
    jobs.append(telegram_process)

    flask_process.start()
    telegram_process.start()
```